# Android Keystore operation failure on cipher.init

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore

In my Android app I insert an item into KeyStore, and occasionally I get a crash related to `InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed` / `KeyStoreException: Key not found`. Usually the operation succeeds, but there is about a 10% fail rate overall. I am thinking it is perhaps a race condition, where the cipher.init will occur before the key creation is finished, but I am unsure. Any ideas on why this code only occasionally fails or how to solve?

Below is the error:

```
    java.lang.Error: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:901)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:926)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
        at com.myapp.service.KeyStoreService.createKeysAndEncrypt(KeyStoreService.kt:32)
        at com.myapp.provision.ProvisionPresenter.createKeysAndEncrypt(ProvisionRepository.kt:26)
        at com.myapp.provision.ProvisionPresenter.certRetrieved(ProvisionPresenter.kt:106)
        at com.myapp.provision.ProvisionPresenter.access$certRetrieved(ProvisionPresenter.kt:17)
        at com.myapp.provision.ProvisionPresenter$postCompleted$1.invoke(ProvisionPresenter.kt:88)
        at com.myapp.provision.ProvisionPresenter$postCompleted$1.invoke(ProvisionPresenter.kt:17)
        at com.myapp.service.NetworkingService$getData$1.onResponse(NetworkingService.kt:110)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key not found
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:821)
```

And here is my code:

```
        val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, context.resources.getString(R.string.key_store_instance))

        val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build()

        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
        val secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey()

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(context.resources.getString(R.string.key_store_transformation))

        //This is where the crash occurs
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        val iv = cipher.iv

        val byteCert = cert.toByteArray()

        val encryption = cipher.doFinal(byteCert)
```

Comment: There's no race condition in this code, it's all single threaded.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. Any idea on what might cause the error?